# Is there any way to get 2 "up" buttons for the Android AppCompat navigation drawers (one on each side)?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-drawable, android-appcompat

I have built an Android app using the AppCompat navigation drawers (one on the left and one on the right). My questions is whether and if so, how, one would go about placing one of the "up" buttons on the title bar, so each drawer has its own button (one on each side of the title bar). I have the following code:

```
new DrawerToggle(this, getLeftDrawerLayout(), R.drawable.imgur_drawer_list_button_shape_left, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer, getLeftDrawerListView(), LeftDrawerDrawerArrayAdapter);

new DrawerToggle(this, getRightDrawerLayout(), R.drawable.imgur_drawer_list_button_shape_right, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer, getRightDrawerListView(), RightDrawerDrawerArrayAdapter);
```

where *DrawerToggle* extends *android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle* and *R.drawable.imgur_drawer_list_button_shape_left* as well as *R.drawable.imgur_drawer_list_button_shape_right* are in the drawable resource directory as required.

Also, the following code is handled in the activity *onCreate* method:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Unfortunately this only produces an application with solely the left-hand drawer "up" button icon, which reacts (i.e. slides in) to both, the left and right drawers...

Can anyone please help and provide a way to have the buttons on either sides of the title bar, each corresponding to its respective drawer?

Thank you sincerely! :)
Piotr.

Answer (score 0):

Having toggles at both sides is never stated in the design guidelines. There is a hacky way to do this, it is real mess, but give it a try.

This includes overriding the functionality of the overflow menu item, which means you will never have it working as it supposed to.

1. Add an menu item that has `showAsAction="never"` to make sure you have always a overflow menu item.
2. Style it as your heart desires
3. Get `View` reference of the [overflow button](https://gist.github.com/NikolaDespotoski/6329946) as following:

   ```
    public static View getOverflowButton(Activity a){
             View homeButton = a.findViewById(android.R.id.home);
               ViewParent parentOfHome = homeButton.getParent().getParent(); //ActionBarView is parent of home ImageView, see layout file in sources
               try{
   ```

   `parentOfHome = parentOfHome.getParent();//get to ActionBarView;
           Class absActionBarView = parentOfHome.getClass().getSuperclass(); //ActionBarView -> AbsActionBarView class
           Field menuPresenter = absActionBarView.getDeclaredField("mActionMenuPresenter"); // ActionMenuPresenter is the object that calls openOverflowMenu() closeOverflowMenu()
           menuPresenter.setAccessible(true);                                    // and contains the overflow button view.
           Object menuPresenterView = menuPresenter.get(parentOfHome);
           Field overflowField = menuPresenterView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mOverflowButton");
            overflowField.setAccessible(true);
            View overFlowButtonView = (View) overflowField.get(menuPresenterView);
            return overFlowButtonView;              

     }
     catch(NoSuchFieldException e){
          Log.e("getOverflowButton()", e.getMessage());

      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
          Log.e("getOverflowButton()", e.getMessage());
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          Log.e("getOverflowButton()", e.getMessage());
      }
       return null;
   }`
4. Add `OnClickListener` to the view reference (anonymous declaration or field). Trivial.
5. Toggle the drawer in the `onClick()`
6. Use `onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)` to animate the drawable as it is animated in the ActionBarDrawerToggle. Basically, it is off-screened-drawable by half and it is moved back and forth by some factor made up from the slideOffset.